# Fill datatable columns from excel as a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, excel, datatable

I am filling a data table from an excel sheet which is formatted (decimals, dates, etc...).

My problem is that the columns are being formatted as the excel sheet, but I need to fill all the columns as string, how can I do that?

My import method:

```
Private Function upload(filename As String) As DataTable
        Dim FilePath__1 As String = "Uploads/"
        Try
            Dim allowdFile As String() = {".xls", ".xlsx"}
            Dim FileExt As String = ".xls"

            Dim isValidFile As Boolean = allowdFile.Contains(FileExt)
            If Not isValidFile Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                Dim filePath__2 As String = Server.MapPath(FilePath__1) & filename

                Dim con As OleDbConnection = Nothing
                If FileExt = ".xls" Then
                    con = New OleDbConnection((Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=") & filePath__2) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
                ElseIf FileExt = ".xlsx" Then
                    con = New OleDbConnection((Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=") & filePath__2) + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
                End If
                con.Open()

                Dim dt As DataTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, Nothing)

                Dim getExcelSheetName As String = dt.Rows(0)("Table_Name").ToString()

                Dim ExcelCommand As New OleDbCommand((Convert.ToString("SELECT * FROM [") & getExcelSheetName) + "]", con)
                Dim ExcelAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand)
                Dim ExcelDataSet As New DataSet()
                ExcelAdapter.Fill(ExcelDataSet)
                con.Close()
                If ExcelDataSet.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    Return ExcelDataSet.Tables(0)
                Else
                    Return Nothing
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Any help would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to loop the rows and use `ToString`:

```
DataTable tblOld = ExcelDataSet.Tables[0];
DataTable tblNew = new DataTable();
foreach (DataColumn col in tblOld.Columns)
    tblNew.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName);
foreach (DataRow rowOld in tblOld.Rows)
{
    DataRow rowNew = tblNew.Rows.Add();
    foreach (DataColumn col in tblOld.Columns)
    {
        rowNew.SetField(col.ColumnName, rowOld.IsNull(col) ? "" : rowOld[col].ToString());
    }
} 
return tblNew;
```

Comment: why are u being sarcastic?? not working I meant the columns are still double, date etc...

Comment: @AliIssa: i didn't want to be sarcastic, but it is difficult to find the reason for an issue if everybody describes it with "it's not working" (not only you). Have you used the debugger to see what happens? Maybe you're swallowing an exception with an empty catch somewhere. My code should work, there is no magic, it just uses `ToString` to convert every cell-value into `String`. How you do check whether it works or not?

Comment: @AliIssa: i have edited my code. The first approach uses the old DataColumns, you need a new DataTbale because all columns should be string.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using IMEX=1 in the your excel connection string as below

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=YourExcelFilePath.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"""
```

This attribute hints the reader to read all values as text